# How to Get Google PlayService user Id when Internet is Not Connected?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am Using GooglePlayService API for my project. And i am able to get the user playGames ID when the Internet is connected using GoogleApiClient.
But for my project I need the user PlayGames ID when Internet is NOT Connected also...
Is there a solution to get the ID locally????
Guys,Help me For the Solution,
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Once you obtain the playGamesID while the internet is connected, you can store that ID in either shared preferences or SQLite Database to use it later again.